# How do i click on a specific element from a list of elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

i have a code that loops through all users on a page and i want it to look for a specific user then click on that user in order to retrieve other info from the user. How do i do that ?

```
const item_Container = await page.$$(".user");
await page.waitFor(1000)
for (const items of item_Container) {
    const item_Name = await items.$(".user__title");
    const name = await items.$eval(".user__title a", e => e.innerHTML);
    let ans = name.includes(kw);
    console.log(ans);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you found the element you can click on it by emulating mouse click:

```js
await items.click();
```

or HTMLElement.click:

```js
await page.evaluate(el => el.click(), items);
```

In my experience, sometimes emulating mouse click doesn't work (element is covered by another element), in those cases `HTMLElement.click` comes in handy.